# How to check or convert to JSON datatype?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using python elastic search client to query an elastic search instance and following an example on how to use it. I ran the code below and got nothing back for the query I'm trying to run.

In the `for` loop below, how can I check the count or what kind of response I'm getting back from elasticsearch, while iterating over `results['hits']['hits']`? Is there a way to convert this to a JSON array?

```
newResults= []

results = es_client(index="sampleindex", doc_type="sampledoc",
                    body={"query": {"match": {"text":sometext}}})
for i, hit in enumerate(results['hits']['hits']):
    newResults.append(hit[i][_id])
    print("%s) %s" % (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['content']))
```

results

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 122,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "someindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "amazon"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "someindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "alibaba"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in your question is syntactically incorrect (note syntax-highlighting). You're probably missing a `"` character (or have one too many).

Comment: I'm not familiar with elasticsearch, but understand JSON formatting (and Python's `json` module) fairly well. If you add an example of what's in `results`, I may be able to show you how to deal with it.

Comment: @martineau - thank you so much. i've updated the question above to include the results. I would like to iterate through the hits array in the results and also only select id and name field from each object in the array and save that to a new json array.

Comment: Unfortunately the data you added to your question isn't valid JSON (there's no closing `}` for either of the two nested `"_source"` dictionaries — can you straighten that out?

Comment: @martineau - just fixed it

Comment: Sorry to say that your change doesn't fix the parsing problem I mentioned — what's in your question is still invalid JSON.

Comment: @martineau - i apologize. updated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is code showing how to use the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module to convert the data in the `results` string into a Python data structure and then display some of its contents.

```
import json

#results = es_client(index="sampleindex", doc_type="sampledoc",
#                    body={"query": {"match": {"text":sometext}}})

results = '''
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 122,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "someindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "amazon"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "someindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Name": "alibaba"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''


results = json.loads(results)  # Deserialize results into Python object.
print(f"There were {len(results['hits']['hits'])} hits:")
print()
for i, hit in enumerate(results['hits']['hits']):
    print(f'hit[{i}]: {json.dumps(hit, indent=4)}')
```

Output:

```
There were 2 hits:

hit[0]: {
    "_index": "someindex",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "Name": "amazon"
    }
}
hit[1]: {
    "_index": "someindex",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "Name": "alibaba"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again. I apolgize as i'm new to python, this is probably very basic questions, to select a particular key can i do -> hit ['_source']['Name'] , and add each of this item to a different python object.

Comment: You could select a specific `hit` by using something like `results['hits']['hits'][index]` where `index` is the integer index of the one desired. This is because `results['hits']['hits']` is a `list` of items (`dict`s).

Comment: thanks. also i want to create another python dictionary object to add these new processed list.

Comment: one last question. i meant how can i create a new dictionary and save the items i select during the enumeration of the results dictonary.

Comment: Saving multiple items in a dictionary would be problematic unless you give each one a unique key — which is probably why elasticsearch is returning a list them that can be referenced by simple integer indices. You could append any you wanted to save by using the `list.append()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220172/discussion-between-tisha-and-martineau).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, a JSON array is a dictionary which include a list of pair matching a key to a value. To do a conversion to a JSON array, think of it like converting to a list of paired elements.

Comment: You are mistaken, a JSON array is _not_ essentially a dictionary. See the [JSON Specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Comment: if there is a example , please provide one

Answer (score 1):

Here are one JSON example:

```
{ "student": {name : "Chris", email: "chris@email.net"}  }
```

Student would be the key. And the rest of the information would be the value, which in turn is a list of key-value pair.

Comment: thanks @Stephan - actually I meant how can i determine the format of the data ( whether or json or not ) and if not json, how can i convert it to json . but looks like i can simply do json.dumps(data) and get the results in python as json.

Comment: Oh ok! In javascript, there is a method stringify() that you can try it out. For example, var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data)